# Button in a case statement, launching a url

Tags: javascript, html, websense

Below is the case statement I'm trying to get to work. I have the formatting down where I want it, however there is no action by the button (onclick) at this point.

```
case 'This Websense category is filtered: <b>Uncategorized</b>.':
document.write('<p><b style="margin-left: 8px;">Help:</b><INPUT TYPE="button" STYLE="margin-left: 64px;" VALUE="Submit UNCATEGORIZED website to Websense" onClick="window.open=(http://aceinsight.websense.com/?url=' + 
'$*WS_URL*$,' + ' "_blank")' + '"></p>\
<hr />\
<p style="margin-left: 108px; color: #FF0000;">Clicking on the above button will open another webpage for Websense to categorize the above site. You will NOT receive a confirmation e-mail or any communication from Websense indicating your request is processing. Please note the response time for your request will vary. Allow three to four (3-4) hours for updates to take effect once approved.</p>');
break;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem... not working? error?

Comment: Not sure if it's the full issue, but you're using `window.open=(...` when it doesn't need the `=`, just `window.open(...`

Comment: You are missing the `"` wrapping the URL in `window.open`.

Comment: `onClick="window.open(\'http://aceinsight.websense.com/?url='+$*WS_URL*$,'\'_blank\')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't bind events inside the elements via html, it makes debugging javascript very difficult. You can create the element with document.write, and then after you do that you can reference the elements using the DOM and add an event that way.
Here's an example:

```
document.write('<button id="foo">Hai!</button>');
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function () {
    window.open('http://aceinsight.websense.com/',"_blank");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5QxuD/

Answer (score 0):

I think your onClick call might be wrong.

Try:

```
window.open("http://aceinsight.websense.com/?url= (rest of your url)")
```

instead of:

```
window.open=("http://aceinsight.websense.com/?url= (rest of your url)")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Comment: Made that change per earlier comment, no change.

Comment: and you are missing the `"`... Should be `window.open("http://aceinsight.websense.com/?url=..."`

Comment: Here is a better link, especially after I removed the =yes from the article:) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open